# How to create a custom template for k2 category and assign this template into Joomla backed?

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-k2, k2

I read many answers on stack overflow and Joomla community but I didn't find how to display the category override template in the [image]backend.

Please check this screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @aragon for editing and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you can follow these steps, I have used on my Joomla site:

Step 1: please go your Joomla root folder go inside > components > com_k2 > templates

Step 2: copy all things inside templates folder and again go inside your main Joomla directory and go inside > templates > now go inside your theme folder or you can say active template folder

Step 3: you can find HTML folder there inside this crate > com_k2 folder now pest your templates folder all files which you copy from components folder

Step 4: now based on your category you can modify default folder for EX: nightlife please check [image: screenshot 1]

Step 5: now login to your Joomla admin and you can see this name in your template selection check [image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Thanks @pixlogix I will try to implement this way and get back to you thanks for detail description

Comment: Thank you @pixlogix for answer. This worked for me. I hope you can help me with other queries about Joomla too.